# Using Java 6's embedded http server for IPC

Tags: java, http, tomcat, jetty, ipc

I am considering using [Java 6's embedded HTTP server](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/jre/api/net/httpserver/spec/com/sun/net/httpserver/package-summary.html) for some sort of IPC with a Java daemon. It works pretty well and it's nice that's already bundled with all Java 6 installations. No need of additional libraries.

However, I would like to know if someone has tried this with production environments with heavy load. Does it perform well? Should I be looking for something more robust such as Tomcat or Jetty?

Answer (score 3):

Well, as much as it saddens me to say bad things about Java, I'd really not recommend it for production use, or any kind of heavy use scenario. Even though it works well for small stuff like unit/integration tests, it has big memory issues when it is used intensivelly, especially when you use it for a big number of connections at once. I've had similar issues to the ones described here:

http://neopatel.blogspot.com/2010/05/java-comsunnethttpserverhttpserver.html

And Jetty is not that good for heavy production usage for pretty much the same reason. I'd go with Tomcat if I were you.

As an alternative, I believe you could consider Java Messaging Service as an alternative to Inter Process Communications and just have a JMS server running (like Active MQ)

Comment: Great link. Saved me a lot of time. I was looking at ActiveMQ before but I really like the simplicity (and ubiquiness) of HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

If you want something that ships with Java have a look at RMI or RMI/IIOP.